# Flutter application is crashed without any log on Android devices

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have a problem with my flutter application. The application is shutting down on some Android devices without any useful crash logs. Also, crashlytics does not send logs in any cases. I have tried to observe different things and I want to give more information about what I have so far. It commonly occurs when I open a video player from the application. I tried to have a small application with a video player, that I used, to reproduce the error but the error did not happen with this app. When a crash is occurred I get logs like this:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@7eaca8c[MainActivity](30160): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7eaca8c[MainActivity](30160): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/ExoPlayerImpl(30160): Init 108e3e3 [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [a3xelte, SM-A310F, samsung, 24]
I/Choreographer(30160): Skipped 43 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/System.out(30160): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(30160): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl@7eaca8c[MainActivity](30160): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][720,1280] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true -880830464} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/ViewRootImpl@7eaca8c[MainActivity](30160): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7eaca8c[MainActivity](30160): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/System.out(30160): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(30160): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
Lost connection to device.
```

There was not any crash report. It just says “Lost connection to device”. Then I tried to track the PID of the application from logcat of the Android device. I did not encounter any useful logs here either. The last thing I saw about the application’s pid was “06-23 17:05:48.253 2738 13601 I ActivityManager: Process [Application package name] (pid 3573) has died(379,50)”. I thought that this might be a memory problem and that the operating system might kill the process of my application so that I wanted to monitor the memory used by the application. I tried the application with a phone that has 6 gb RAM. And my application's memory consumption was 1.6 GB at most. and I do not know what can cause such a big memory consumption.

The problem is observed with different phone models and different Android versions. The problem is not encountered on any iOS device. Devices with the problem and their Android versions can be seen below (but probably it can be encountered on other devices):

- Samsung Galaxy A3 2016 | Android 7.0
- Samsung Galaxy A10 | Android 10
- Xiaomi Mi 10T | Android 11

It would be very nice if you have any idea what is wrong with the application to help me with that issue.

Comment: Hi ! It may be a dumb solution, but have you tried to connect your phones to your PC with new/others cables ? Since the only log is `Lost connection to device.` it seems that they just got unplug.

Comment: Yes, I tried with several different cables. On the other hand, I was able to see the device and logcat of device from my PC after the crash.  @BLKKKBVSIK

Comment: show your code or try to put your video payer in try/catch block and see exception

Comment: or try to run `adb logcat` in terminal

Comment: I tried to run `adb logcat`. There was no crash log there, either. @UsamaAltaf

Answer (score 0):

First guess would be that there is some initial configuration going wrong. Check if all the external libraries and tool you use are correctly connecting and launching. Use some loggers and be sure to handle errors correctly.

Also, if you have an error regarding the video library you're using, checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880525/flutter-app-crashes-when-video-player-loads-hls-video) that might match your issue: